# Table relationships across 3 tables and updating all with a single slicer

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have 3 tables with data. All of which have a username column and I'm trying to connect them.

For this purpose I have created a 4th table which is basically just the User directory (where each username is unique). Then, I have created relationships between each of the data tables with the directory using excel 2013's data model functions.

Now, I have made several pivot tables off of the data and want to be able to filter them based on a single slicer for Username. It works for 2 out of the 3 tables, but I can't get it to work for the third one and I absolutely can't understand why.

If I , however, add another slicer based on the 3rd table, the filter does work.

Is there a way to do this or would it be better for me to pre-filter the source data of that pesky 3rd table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data. See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create nice data tables you can paste into your question.